# how to pass the event object to a function within an object

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Tying to pass the event object to a function within an object using the .on and click handler. It does not seem to be working the way I thought it would an so the initial event.preventDefault() does not work. Since the event.preventDefault() does not work the submit button automatically opens the mail.php page which is obviously not what I am wanting. If someone could help figure this out or steer me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

My script:

```
(function(){
    "strict";
    var portfolio = {
        email: function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("hello people");
            var form = $('#contact');
            var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
            var formData = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mailer.php',
                data: formData
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
                $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
                $(formMessages).addClass('success');
                console.log(response);

                // Set the message text.
                $(formMessages).html('<p class="success">Message has been sent succesfully! Thank you '+ $('#f_name').val() +', a response will be returned in less than one business day.</p>');
                // Clear the form.
                $('#f_name').val('');
                $('#f_email').val('');
                $('#f_message').val('');
                $('#f_website').val('');
                $('#f_budget').val('');
                $('#f_hear').val('');
                $('#f_startdate').val('');
                $('#f_phone').val('');
                form.fadeOut('slow').remove();
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
                $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                $(formMessages).addClass('error');

                // Set the message text.
                if (data.responseText !== '') {
                    $(formMessages).html('<p>'+data.responseText+'</p>');
                } else {
                    $(formMessages).html('<p>Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.</p>');
                }
            });
        },
    }; 

$('body').on('click', '.contact', portfolio.email(event));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
$('body').on('click', '.contact', portfolio.email(event));
```

then the event will be sent to whatever is returned by `portfolio.email(event)`, which is of course invalid.

Just pass the function name:

```
$('body').on('click', '.contact', portfolio.email);
```

Comment: I tried that initially and the e.preventDefault() does not work.

Comment: So i thought i would try and see if it would work if i passed the event object  from the on click event and that failed as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "the e.preventDefault() is not working"? What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: the form from submitting and directing to the mail.php file

Comment: for some reason i tried what you had said and it worked this time. Codekit must have froze when i tried it last time or i forgot to hit save . thank you for your help.

Comment: So the submit button has the class 'contact'?

Comment: Correct, the submit button has the class 'contact'.

Comment: I stripped the portfolio object to just show you the email function within it. am loading in pages so when the page first loads the contact form and fields do not exist yet.